# Shortcut for base mode in maya

Tags: maya, mel

Is there a base mode in **Maya**? If yes, then How to go to base mode? What is the shortcut key?

I'm using Maya 2017 student edition. I was following a video on YouTube, where I came across base mode. I don't know how to go to base mode.

Comment: there's no root node in a Maya scene, at least there's no single node to which everything else is connected.  For any particular node there are may be a parent -- by default, you get the parent for the current selection using the up-arrow key

Comment: Do you mean batch mode? Aka Maya commandline headless mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard about any `base mode in Maya` since 2001. I suppose you're talking about shortcuts for changing a quality display setting for NURBS/Poly in Maya. Or shortcuts for shading. Or object/component mode.

Here are Display Quality shortcuts and their MEL equivalents for Script Editor.

<kbd>1</kbd> – Rough quality display setting

<kbd>2</kbd> – Medium quality display setting

<kbd>3</kbd> – Smooth quality display setting

<kbd>0</kbd> – Default quality display setting

```
displaySmoothness -divisionsU 0 -divisionsV 0 -pointsWire 4 -pointsShaded 1 -polygonObject 1;
displaySmoothness -divisionsU 1 -divisionsV 1 -pointsWire 8 -pointsShaded 2 -polygonObject 2;
displaySmoothness -divisionsU 3 -divisionsV 3 -pointsWire 16 -pointsShaded 4 -polygonObject 3;    
displaySmoothness -polygonObject 0;
```

Also, there are two shortcuts for wireframe/shaded geometry:

<kbd>4</kbd> – Wireframe Mode

<kbd>5</kbd> – Smooth Shade All Mode

Also, there are five shortcuts for object/component mode. These ones you can use for polygonal object's components:

<kbd>F8</kbd> – Object/Component Switch

<kbd>F9</kbd> – Show Vertices for selection

<kbd>F10</kbd> – Show Edges for selection

<kbd>F11</kbd> – Show Faces for selection

<kbd>F12</kbd> – Show UVs for selection